# Javascript: How to convert given date into readable format

Tags: javascript

I have date in ISO-format like:

```
2016-02-17T16:40:30
```

How can I convert it to a human-readable date, for example:

```
17 Feb 2016 16:40
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

First of all, you need to create a date using your original date string.

```
var d = new Date('2016-02-17T16:40:30');
```

And then you can use this to fetch a readable date format:

```
d.toDateString();
```

Will return:

> Wed Feb 17 2016

Comment: but I lost the time in this way

Comment: You can use  `d.toUTCString()` instead, or a combination of functions like  `d.getUTCHours()` and  `d.getUTCMinutes()` to construct your own string.

Comment: There is also [`toLocaleDateString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) if you wanted localized output.