# How to Convert a string date to a more readable version

Tags: javascript, date

I have a date in my database like this
`2021/04/26`

And I wanna convert this to string date to: **Monday, April 04**

I have tried In many different ways. I am very week in working with dates in JavaScript
.

I tried to do like this
`new Date('2021/04/26').getDate() // Which return very strange date.`

Can Anyone help me to convert that string to this **Monday, April 04**

Comment: JS's native Date object is pretty useless at this task. There are a number of 3rd-party libraries such as momentJS which make it a lot easier to parse and format dates. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26500694/convert-date-from-one-format-to-another-format-in-javascript

Comment: I hope that database-date is stored as some *date* type and not that exact string?

Comment: You may refer this <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35577874/javascript-how-to-convert-given-date-into-readable-format>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method 1:**
By using only the build in functions this is the closest you can get to your example:

```
new Date('2021/04/26').toDateString()
```

**Method 2:**
Do it on your own like this:

```
  const months = {
  0: 'January',
  1: 'February',
  2: 'March',
  3: 'April',
  4: 'May',
  5: 'June',
  6: 'July',
  7: 'August',
  8: 'September',
  9: 'October',
  10: 'November',
  11: 'December'
}

const days = [
  'Sunday',
  'Monday',
  'Tuesday',
  'Wednesday',
  'Thursday',
  'Friday',
  'Saturday'
]

let yourDate = new Date('2021/04/26');
let yourDateString = days[yourDate.getDay()]+', '+months[yourDate.getMonth()]+' '+yourDate.getFullYear();
```

RESULT: "Monday, April 2021"

**Method 3:**
Use a third party library.

Comment: Whether or not you get the expected result from `new Date('2021/04/26')` is very problematic, see [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)

Answer (score 1):

I will leave the parsing of the date into a Date object out of this answer. Just passing the string as-is *might* work, or it might break on some setups/locales. You are usually better off manually parsing it and explicitly setting year, month and date.

You can print the date in a more readable format using `Date.toLocaleDateString` ([mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString)). This does not allow you to get your date in any format you can possibly desire, but it does a reasonable job in getting your date in a readable format for the language you want to display it in.

You can get the options from [the implementation of the localisation helper](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat).

```js
const currentDate = new Date();
console.log(currentDate.toLocaleDateString('en-gb', { weekday: 'long', year: 'numeric', month: 'short', day: 'numeric' }));
console.log(currentDate.toLocaleDateString('en-gb', { weekday: 'narrow', year: '2-digit', month: 'long', day: '2-digit' }));
```

If you want full control over what you output, you will need a library. Selecting that library is out-of-scope for Stackoverflow though, so I will not suggest one here.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is to output the date in that format, and not do any date based logic, you could convert the date when selecting from the database (you can of course still select the original date column at the same time). This depends on using the correct date type for the column.

For MySQL:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

`SELECT date_format( DATE_COLUMN, '%W, %M %d' ) as NEW_DATE, ...`

You could also convert it using a server side language like PHP if you are using one. If you let us know how you are fetching and outputting the data there might be a better way.

Comment: Not sure why this has been downvoted, would love to know why. Post doesn't specifically say the date needs to be converted with JS, and date is stored in database so it's possible the conversion could be done on server side, especially with the seeming difficultly and limitations a JS method would entail.